# ConstraintLayout not working in GUI editor Android Studio 3.0 - Canary 4

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-constraintlayout, android-studio-3.0

I'm running into problems when editing layouts that contain a ConstraintLayout element in Android Studio 3.0.

My dependencies are as follows:

```
        project.ext.support_library_version = '26.0.0-beta2'

        dependencies {
            compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta1'
            compile "com.android.support:palette-v7:${project.ext.support_library_version}"
            compile "com.android.support:support-v13:${project.ext.support_library_version}"
            compile "com.android.support:customtabs:${project.ext.support_library_version}"
            compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${project.ext.support_library_version}"
         ...
}
```

The error showing in the UI editor is:

```
The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
 Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE.  If this is an unexpected error you can also try to build the project, then manually refresh the layout.
```

The stacktrace showing is the following:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Entries for a declare-styleable should be after the array declaration.
    at com.android.tools.idea.res.AppResourceRepository.getDeclaredArrayValues(AppResourceRepository.java:634)
    at com.android.tools.idea.res.ResourceClassGenerator.generateStyleable(ResourceClassGenerator.java:249)
    at com.android.tools.idea.res.ResourceClassGenerator.generate(ResourceClassGenerator.java:120)
    at com.android.tools.idea.res.ResourceClassRegistry.findClassDefinition(ResourceClassRegistry.java:102)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:101)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:215)
    at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.init(ConstraintLayout.java:494)
    at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.<init>(ConstraintLayout.java:466)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:481)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:264)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:222)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:206)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:337)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:348)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:248)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:733)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:334)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:382)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:193)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:591)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$3(RenderTask.java:739)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Cleaning/building/invalidate caches etc. Does not help. Note that the app is functioning perfectly, it's only the UI Editor that is not working anymore.
Who faces the same issue, or has a solution for this?

Comment: That setup works for me without errors.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There's a problem with support library 26.0.0-beta2 -- you need to switch back to beta 1 in order for things to work in Android Studio.

Comment: Thanks this solved the issue mentioned above. I hope it will help others as well!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had been using Constraint for 2 days without the preview and it was quite not pleasant